# How to get formatted address from ip address in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, geolocation, location

I have used following code in javascript to get longitude,latitude,city,country etc.
But i need full formatted address how i can get this?

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (location) {
                // example where I update content on the page.
                jQuery('#city').html(location.city);
                jQuery('#region-code').html(location.region_code);
                jQuery('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
                jQuery('#areacode').html(location.areacode);
                jQuery('#ip').html(location.ip);
                jQuery('#zipcode').html(location.zipcode);
                jQuery('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
                jQuery('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
                jQuery('#country-name').html(location.country_name);
                jQuery('#country-code').html(location.country_code);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by _full formatted address_?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be possible to get the full formatted address from the user's IP address because the ISPs don't give this information. Else, everyone could know where you live :)

You can use services that will give you an approximated position and information about the area.

For example, you could use [userinfo.io](http://userinfo.io) which is a free ip-to-geolocation service. The accuracy is approximately this:

- Continent: ~99.9%
- Country: ~95%
- City: ~50%
- Exact position (latitude/longitude): ~50%

And the data comes from several databases so it's pretty good. In practice the more developed countries will be very accurate (I live in the US and the geolocation is within 1 block) and the less developed countries may give you a wider approximation area.

To use it, just add the dependency to the library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/userinfo/1.0.0/userinfo.min.js"></script>
```

And get the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
UserInfo.getInfo(function(data) {
  // the "data" object contains the info
}, function(err) {
  // the "err" object contains useful information in case of an error
});
</script>
```

The data looks like that:

```
{
  request_date: "2014-09-18T04:11:25.154Z",
  ip_address: "192.77.237.95",
  position: {
    latitude: 37.7758,
    longitude: -122.4128,
    accuracy: 3   // This is the accuracy radius, in kilometers
  },
  continent: {
    name: "North America",
    code: "NA",
  },
  country: {
    name: "United States",
    code: "US",
  },
  city: {
    name: "San Francisco",
    code: "94103"
  }
}
```

*Disclaimer: I wrote and I maintain this service*